# Compression in Scala

Tags: scala, vector, compression, long-integer, bit

I'm working on Scala with VERY larg lists of *Int* (maybe *large*) and I need to compress them and to hold it in memory.

The only requirement is that I can pull (and decompress) the first number on the list to work with, whithout touching the rest of the list.

I have many good ideas but most of them translate the numbers to bits.
Example:

you can write any number *x* as the tuple |log(x)|,x-|log(x)| the first element we right it as a string of 1's and a 0 at the end (Unary Code) and the second in binary. e.g:

> 1 -> 0,1 -> 0 1
>
> ...
>
> 5 -> 2,1 -> 110 01
>
> ...
>
> 8 -> 3,0  -> 1110 000
>
> 9 -> 3,1  -> 1110 001
>
> ...

While a Int takes a fixed 32 bits of memory and a long 64, with this compression *x* requires *2log(x)* bits for storage and can grow indefinetly. This Compression does reducememory in most cases.

How would you handle such type of data? Is there something such as bitarray or something?

Any other way to compress such data in Scala?

Thanks

Comment: How large are your lists?  Perhaps you don't need the fancy footwork.  Otherwise it sounds as if you have a very specific problem and it is unlikely that you'll get something out of the box.

Comment: The Lists may have millions of entries and they will be read/written from/on the disc and handle many at a time. So the compression will also help performance (reducing I/O I think).

I hope someone knows a better way to represent such a list in Scala (Maybe a byteArray, I don't know)

Comment: Has this to be a List of values? Could it be a set?

Comment: Good question. The order is really important but nothing else. It can be any ORDERED structure (i.e. it can be an array or map, but not a set)

Comment: All values are uniformly distributed?

Comment: I'd say there compression won't work in this scenario. Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem .

Comment: When you say "translate the numbers to bits," what do you mean? When you say "numbers" do you mean numeric strings? You should represent these as Int or Long or, if necessary due to their range, as BigInteger. If these integers are immense, then you could consider compressing their binary representation. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I added an example of what I'm thinking. But my question is what data type can I use to handle seqences of bits like that (If I store it in a Array[Int] it will take more memory than the original data)

Comment: So you're not storing integers, you're storing a largish bit string? And you need to be able to remove individual bits from the front, one at a time? I'd represent them as an array of Int with a number indicating how many bits have been removed. When the number of unused array slots at the beginning is too big, regenerate the array with no unused slots at the front.

Comment: I suggest you remove Scala from your question and make it about algorithms, language-agnostic.

Comment: Yes. My problem is an int takes 32bits of memory, while I just want to store 1 (it's a waste of space if I represent the bits as Int).

Comment: Daniel, my question is more related to the data structure that I can use to store the list of bits. I'm looking for a data structure in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the sparseness and range of your data set, you may keep your data as a list of deltas instead of numbers. That's used for sound compression, for instance, and can be both lossy or lossless, depending on your needs.

For instance, if you have `Int` numbers but know they will hardly ever be more than a (signed) `Byte` apart, you could do something like this list of bytes:

```
-1           // Use -1 to imply the next number cannot be computed as a byte delta
0, 0, 4, 0   // 1024 encoded as bytes
1            // 1025 as a delta
-5           // 1020 as a delta
-1           // Next number can't be computed as a byte delta
0, 0, -1, -1 // 65535 encoded as bytes -- -1 doesn't have special meaning here
10           // 65545 as a delta
```

So you don't have to handle bits using this particular encoding. But, really, you won't get good answers without a very clear indication of the particular problem, the characteristics of the data, etc.

Rereading your question, it seems you are not *discarding* compression techniques that turn data into bits. If not, then I suggest Huffman -- predictive if needed -- or something from the Lempel-Ziv family.

And, no, Scala has no library to handle binary data, unfortunately. Though paulp probably has something like that in the compiler itself.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea.

I guess we could use an array of bytes to "package" bits. It would serve as a list of bits (packed in groups of 8). Do you think this could work in terms of performance?